# setWidth() Button Android

Tags: android, button, view, size, width

I've created a Button placed in a RelativeLayout and I'd like to set its size. But I can only set a larger size that the original one, for example I can resize it to 200dp but no to 20dp.

Is there a solution ?

Here is my code

```
Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
myLayout.addView(b);
b.setWidth(200); // Work
b.setWidth(20); // Don't work
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the `Button` has a minimum width of `64dip` by default. Set it to `0` before setting the width.

```
b.setMinimumWidth(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width of the button by giving values in the properties window of the design panel of the xml.on the right side of the UI design.
You can use small button instead of button to make it a 20dpi.